# d3 line drawing v4 - interpolation bug

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to fix this path drawing chart from d3v3 to d3v4

//v3 works
http://jsfiddle.net/0ht35rpb/245/

```
var bezierLine = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) { return d[0]; })
    .y(function(d) { return d[1]; })
```

//v4 broken
http://jsfiddle.net/0ht35rpb/246/

```
var bezierLine = d3.line()
    .x(function(d) { return d[0]; })
    .y(function(d) { return d[1]; })
```

I believe its the animation arc tweening interpolation aspects..

```
.attrTween("stroke-dasharray", function() {
            var len = this.getTotalLength();
            return function(t) { 
            return (
            d3.interpolateString("0," + len, len + ",0")
            )(t) 
            };
        });
```

I tried to get this demo working to assess
http://bl.ocks.org/emmasaunders/c25a147970def2b02d8c7c2719dc7502

http://jsfiddle.net/0ht35rpb/249/

Comment: Your code is fine, your fiddle is broken.  You are missing a close `</script>` tag when you load `d3` in the HTML section:  `<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>`

Comment: cheers man - lol http://jsfiddle.net/0ht35rpb/255/

Comment: here is a d3v3 version - http://jsfiddle.net/0ht35rpb/254/